# How to resize images in bash script using ImageMagick and obtained variables?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, image-resizing

I wrote the following script to resize images using information from $array (image sizes and image links):

```
for ((a=0; a < ${#array[*]}; a++))
  do
    imagesize=$(echo "$a: ${array[$a]}" | grep "<icon"| grep -E -o "height=\"(\d+)" | grep -E -o "\d+")
    imagelink=$(echo "$a: ${array[$a]}" | grep "<icon"| grep -E -o "[^\"\'=[:space:]]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)")
    convert icon.png -resize $imagesizex$imagesize! ../../$imagelink
  done
```

However, an image was resized in the following way: 36x1024 instead of 36x36. The same happened to all other images (48x1024, 72x1024, 96x1024 ...).
The original image is 1024x1024.

Could you please help me to make the resizement correctly. I suppose, that in line:

```
convert icon.png -resize $imagesizex$imagesize! ../../$imagelink
```

bash does not recognize $imagesizex. How to avoid this mistake?

Comment: Please try: `-resize "${imagesize}x${imagesize}"`

Comment: As @tshiono says, but retain your `!` after the `}` too.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Exactly!